# Change Kendo Grid Cell With Ajax Response When Another Cell Changes

Tags: ajax, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Using a Kendo grid with 3 columns, I have an event that fires when the first column is changed that makes an ajax call and returns some data.  I want to update the second column with the returned data but I'm not having any luck and I'm not even sure if this is the correct approach.  I can change the second column with static data by adding a change event to my datasource of my grid, but that of course doesn't help.  The only examples I can seem to find show changing another column with client side data, not data returned from the server.  Here's what I have so far:

```
 $("#manualStatsGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: this.GetManualStatisticsDataSource(),
        sortable: true,
        pageable: false,
        filterable: true,
        toolbar: ["create"],
        editable: "inline",
        messages: {
            commands: {
                create: "Add New Statistic"
            }
        },
        edit: function (e) {
            var _this = _manualStats;
            var input = e.container.find(".k-input");

            var value = input.val();                

            input.keyup(function(){
                value = input.val();
            });                

            $("[name='Statistic']", e.container).blur(function(){
                var input = $(this);
                $("#log").html(input.attr('name') + " blurred " + value);

                //valid the GL account number
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: _this.ValidateGlUrl,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { glNumber: value },
                    success: function (response) {
                        var newDescription = response.Data.description;
                        console.log(newDescription);
                        //change description column here?
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });


            });
        },
        columns: [
            { field: "Statistic" },
            { field: "Description" },
            { field: "Instructions" },
            { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px"}
        ]            
    });
}

this.GetManualStatisticsDataSource = function () {
    var _this = _manualStats;
    var dataSource = {
        type: "json",
        transport: {
            read: {
                type: "POST",
                url: _this.GetManualStatisticsUrl,
                dataType: "json"
            },
            update: {
                type: "POST",
                url: _this.UpdateManualStatisticsUrl,
                dataType: "json"
            },
            create: {
                type: "POST",
                url: _this.CreateManualStatisticsUrl,
                dataType: "json"
            },
            destroy: {
                type: "POST",
                url: _this.DeleteManualStatisticsUrl,
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "Statistic",
                fields: {                        
                    Statistic: {
                        type: "string",
                        editable: true,
                        validation: { required: true, pattern: "[0-9]{5}.[0-9]{3}", validationmessage: "Please use the following format: #####.###" }
                    },
                    Description: { editable: false },
                    Instructions: { type: "string", editable: true }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `edit` event, you have `e.model`. The model has the method `set()` which can change any dataItem's property value:

```
edit: function (e) {
    ...
    var editEvent = e; // Creates a local var with the edit's event 'e' variable to be available inside the 'blur' event
    $("[name='Statistic']", e.container).blur(function() {
        ...
        $.ajax({
            ...
            success: function(e, response) { // 'e' inside this callback is the 'editEvent' variable
                e.model.set("Description", response.Data.description); // e.model.set() will change any model's property you want
            }.bind(null, editEvent) // Binds the 'editEvent' variable to the success param
        });
    });
```

[Working demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/OSOGa)

Made this snippet of top of my head. Tell me if there is something wrong with it.

Comment: For some reason "e.model.set" isn't changing the grid, "e.model.Description = response.Data.description" changes the grid after I click the update button but not after leaving the Statistic column, your demo works perfectly, guessing I have something wired up incorrectly?

Comment: Your answer was perfect, I had the schema for the description column set to "editable: false" because I don't want to allow users to edit that column, not sure yet how to get around that.  Thanks for your help and the demo!

Comment: @tcrafton I was almost sure I had achieve that before, but I can't remember how I did it. The closest I can get now is this http://dojo.telerik.com/OSOGa/2, but it isn't smoothy enought.. not good.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll keep looking into it but it may have to be an option.  Really appreciate the help!